# What is an easy way to work subsurface scattering into a raycaster?

Tags: raycasting, raytracing

I've got some neat effects with path tracing:

[image: scattering]

I want to add in an ability to do [subsurface scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsurface_scattering), but I'm unsure of the general algorithm.  With path tracing, it's:

```
foreach pixel:
    trace( ray into scene )
        color = 0
        if( ray hits an object )
            if( that object is emissive )
                color += object.emissive_color
            if( that object is translucent )
                color += trace( object.refracted ray into scene )
            if( that object is specular )
                color += trace( object.specularly-reflected ray into scene )
            if( that object is diffuse )
                color += trace( object.random-direction reflection ray into scene )

        return color
```

That's the rough outline.  Where does subsurface scattering go and how can I integrate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach to subsurface scattering in offline rendering is the so-called "dipole approximation", which is described in the paper [A Practical Model for Subsurface Light Transport](http://graphics.ucsd.edu/~henrik/papers/bssrdf/) by Henrik Wann Jensen and others.  Unfortunately, I can't do much more than point you at the paper, as I haven't studied it enough to understand it in detail.  Googling for "dipole subsurface scattering" will also find you a few more links.

Jensen also has a page with some more images and links to other papers on the subject [here](http://graphics.ucsd.edu/~henrik/images/subsurf.html).

Finally, it's also possible to simulate subsurface scattering with a brute force Monte Carlo approach, using either path tracing or photon mapping, as long as your renderer supports volumetrics.  You pretty much just make a volume that has an extremely high scattering coefficient (orders of magnitude more than you'd use for smoke/haze/etc.)  This is very slow though, even by Monte Carlo standards.

Comment: Yes, I came across this paper.  It looks interesting, but I was actually interested in the Monte Carlo approach (the actual raycasting physics, without the dipole precompute).  "Volumetric raytracing" is the answer I was looking for, it seems!

Comment: @bobobobo Ahh, I see.  "Single scattering" and "multiple scattering" are also good keywords to search for.  If you don't have it already, [PBR](http://www.amazon.com/Physically-Based-Rendering-Second-Edition/dp/0123750792/) is also a great reference on volumetric raytracing as well as all other aspects of raytracing.